# Weight column doesn't appear in search result

Tags: sphinx

I'm learning about Sphinx with the book "[Introduction to Search with Sphinx](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596809539.do)" and the first query with the test data:

```
mysql> select * from test1 where match('test');
```

should produce this output:

[image]

but this is the output I am getting:

[image]

Why is the **weight** column missing from my result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SphinxQL used to do a number of things 'magically', one of them was automatically add columns depending on the query. But it was decided that magic behaviour often confused programs (wasnt sure if the column would be there or not)

... so now, columns are only there if you explicitly ask for them (although can still use * for id+attributes)

```
mysql> select *,weight() as weight from test1 where match('test');
```